Coding QML where properties like 'parent.horizontalCenter' are not being auto-completed in my QtCreator
The auto-completed Can`t give me parent.horizontalCenter or bottom When I write "parent.hor" or "parent.bot" but other parameter can show such as height,width.
my Qt version is 6.7.1 which compile with msvc2022-pe-64bit,QtCreator version is 10.0.2
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: backgroud
        source: "./images/background.png"
    }
    Image {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        id: pole
        source: "./images/pole.png"
    }
}

I tried import QtQuick.Layout but it not work
